# how to unlock file without kill related process

Tags: windows

I currently use OpenedFilesView for control file handle but it is windows based. i want console application for build automation process. i want something like following code

```
unlockfile file.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My tool of choice for this scenario is LockHunter.

It also sports a command-line interface in addition to a GUI. It works on Windows 7 x68 and x64 editions.

http://lockhunter.com/manual.htm

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft/Sysinternals tool [Handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) tool can unlock files:

```
handle.exe -c 0x38 -p 1234
```

You will probably want to automate first running the following to find any usages of app.exe

```
handle.exe \Path\to\app.exe
```

You would then need to interpret the results to get the handle id and process id to be passed into the first command.

*Do be warned though, closing handles behind application's back is likely to lead to instability in the application that had the handle open.*

Comment: IMHO , handle.exe able to close file by handle only but i want close file by filename

Answer (score 3):

To complement the answer about handle.exe.

[Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) features GUI with the same functionality: search for handle by pattern, list process handles, close any of them.

Comment: I already had this installed, so this tip saved me from downloading extra things. Thanks!

Comment: Similar question and answer with more details: [How do you find what process is holding a file open in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows)